# VIM internal count variable

Tags: vim

I discovered VIM has internal variables count and prevcount.  However the count variable is somehow different from prevcount as per the following examples...

`echo v:prevcount` gives the last normal count value that you typed.
`echo prevcount` gives error "undefined variable".
`echo v:count` gives the value 0 seemingly every time.
`echo count` also gives the value 0 every time.

So why didn't `echo count` give an error like `echo prevcount` did?

Note that `echo l:count` also gives error "undefined variable", as does every other possible prefix except `v:`.

Answer (score 4):

You'll find the answer under `:help v:count`:

> ```
>   [...]
>   "count" also works, for backwards compatibility.
> ```

In early Vim versions, there was no `v:` prefix. They later realized that it's better to have a dedicated namespace for internal variables. `v:prevcount` was only introduced later, so there's no need to be backward compatible there. **You should always use the `v:count` variant today.**